# Trying out a problem but code I had written is not giving output for large numbers. why?

Tags: c++, c++11, math

I was trying this question.

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

And I had written the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#define num 600851475143
using namespace std;
int isprime(unsigned long long int n)
{
  unsigned long long int c=0;
  for(unsigned long long int i=2;i<n;i++)
  {
      if(n%i==0)
      {
          c++;
          break;
     }
  }
  if(c==0)
  {
      return 1;
  } 
  else
  {
      return 0;
  }
 }
 int main()
 {
 unsigned long long int a,i,n=num;
 while(n-- && n>1)
 {  
     if(isprime(n)==1 && num%n==0)
     {
         cout<<n;
         break;
     }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

The problem occurring with the code is it is working for 13195 and other small values. But not getting any output for 600851475143. Can anyone explain why it is not working for large value and also tell the changes that should be made in these to get the correct output.

Comment: Probably the program runs for a very long time to finish and you do not have a newline in your output, which would flush the stdout buffer. Add some `cout`s in the code to see if it is still running.

Comment: Add a print every 100 000 iterations, the number you are looking for is around 7000-ish, you can estimate how long it will take to iterate from 600851475143 down to 7000.

Comment: The way your program is written: it probably didn't, yet, got to the largest prime. The largest prime is `6857`. So you would need to run more than 600 billion "isprime" checks.. Which, loop over the whole number..

Comment: your code is unnecessarily complex for variable/values of 'c' and the break. just drop c all together and put a return 0 instead of the break.
other than that you only need to probe for division by other, smaller primes up to the square root of the number in question.

Comment: I suggest to change order of check, modulo is faster than `isprime`. (and once you found a divisor, you might "reduce" `n` too).

Comment: largest possible candidate prime factors of `600851475143` would be `600851475143` itself, then `600851475143/2`... So currently, your check from `600851475143 - 1` `600851475143/2 + 1` (300425737570 numbers) is necessary wrong.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389675/largest-prime-factor-of-600851475143

Comment: why not just do factorization?
applying factoring will reduce the search space dramatically.
when all factors are known then the largest factor can be found easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code snippets are from c (but should run quite nice with c++ as well):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define uIntPrime       unsigned long long int
#define uIntPrimeFormat "llu"

uIntPrime findSmallestPrimeFactor(uIntPrime num)
{
    uIntPrime limit = num / 2 + 1;

    for(uIntPrime i=2; i<limit; i++)
    {
        if((num % i) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

uIntPrime findLargestPrimeFactor(uIntPrime num)
{
    uIntPrime largestPrimeFactor = 1; // start with the smallest possible value

    while (num > 1) {
        uIntPrime primeFactor = findSmallestPrimeFactor(num);
        if (primeFactor > largestPrimeFactor) largestPrimeFactor = primeFactor;
        num = num / primeFactor;
    }

    return largestPrimeFactor;
}
```

How can this work?

(first function:) Counting the numbers up from 2 means you are starting with prime factors on the lower end. (Numbers that are non-prime when counting are just not working out as fraction-less divisors and at the same time their prime number factor components were already probed because they are lower.)

(second function:) If a valid factor is found then the factor is pulled out from the number in question. Thus the search for the now smallest prime in the pulled-out number can repeat. (The conditional might probably be superfluous due to lower numbers are found first anyway - but it might resemble a search pattern you are familiar with - like in a minimum/maximum/other-criteria search. I am now leaving it up to you to proof it right or wrong with testing with your own main routine.)
The stop condition is about having the last factor extracted means dividing the value by itself and getting a value of 1 for num.

(There is for sure still much space for speeding this up!)